# I want to use tflite model in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, machine-learning

I created a new model and exported it as a .tflite model. Is there a way to use this model inside dart. When I input an array to the model, it make predictions and sends true or false. I want to do this inside dart. Which means, when I input a array to the model, I should be able to get true or false.

`

```
# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('autoencoder') # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

`

This is the code I wrote and got .tflite file. How to use this file inside dart to make predictions to a given array.

Comment: You can use google_ml_kit https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit, for Flutter,Look at the example https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/packages/google_ml_kit/example